# Rewriterule : php page to another (with parameters) cause a 500 error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a simple question but can't find the answer.

I have a page: http://www.mysite.com/overview.php?lang=en&TM=15 and

I want to access a new page : http://www.mysite.com/aboutus/overview.php?lang=en&TM=15

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^overview\.php\?lang=fr&TM=([0-9]+)&TM=([0-9]+)*$ /aboutus/overview.php?lang=$1&TM=$2 [R=301, L]
```

Any idea to solve my problem ?
Thank you in advance
Dominique

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/overview\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /aboutus/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**[QSA]** option will Rewrite url along with query parameters, so no need to match separately for `lang=en&TM=15` (if you want to pass same request parameters while rewriting url)